# PHP query string

Tags: php

hi  i am facing a strang problem that a part of querystring are showing in title on page i have used following function

```
         function tabVideo(){
global $db,$bll;
          ?>

       <table width="100%" align="center" border="0"  cellspacing="0" bgcolor="CCCDE2">
              <?
            $page_vi=$_GET['page_vi'];
              $rec_per_page=3;
              if (empty($page_vi)) $page_vi = 1;
                $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rec FROM think_video";
                     $rs = $db->sql_fetchrow($db->sql_query($sql));
                         $total_rec = $rs['total_rec'];
                 // find out how many pages
                    $total_pages = ceil($total_rec / $rec_per_page);
              // find out where to start at
                  $start = ($page_vi*$rec_per_page)-$rec_per_page;

                       $sql="select id,videotitle,videodescription,videofile,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(videodate),'%d/%m/%Y') as videodate, videodate as vd from think_video order by vd DESC limit $start,$rec_per_page";
                $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
             while($row=$db->sql_fetchrow($result)){
                   ?>
                  <tr>
                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding-top:15px; padding-left:20px">
         <script type="text/javascript">
        if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
            alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
        } else {
            AC_FL_RunContent(
                'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
                'width', '520',
                'height', '300',
                'src', 'fplayer/lib/fPlayer/fPlayerIn',
                'quality', 'high',
                'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                'align', 'middle',
                'play', 'true',
                'loop', 'true',
                'scale', 'exactfit',
                'wmode', 'window',
                'devicefont', 'false',
                'id', 'fPlayer',
                'bgcolor', '#000000',
                'name', 'fPlayer',
                'menu', 'true',
                'FlashVars', 'playList=fplayer/db/xml/<?=trim($row['id'])?>.xml',
                'allowFullScreen', 'true',
                'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                'movie', 'fplayer/lib/fPlayer/fPlayerIn',
                'salign', ''
                ); //end AC code
        }
    </script> 
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding-left:20px">
    <div class="text3"><?=$row['videodate']." ".trim($row['videotitle'])?></div>
    <div class="text4 b" align="justify"><?=trim($row['videodescription'])?></span>     </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="solid-line" align="justify" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
             <? }
        if($page_vi>1)
               $paging .= '<a href="think-in-de-pers.php?tabid=div_video&page_vi='.($page_vi-1).'**#fragment-1**" class="link8" style="float:left"><< terug naar vorige video&rsquo;s&nbsp;</a>';
                  if($page_vi<$total_pages)
                  $paging .= '<a href="think-in-de-pers.php?tabid=div_video&page_vi='.($page_vi+1).'**#fragment-1**" class="link8" style="float:right">klik hier voor oudere video&rsquo;s >>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>';
    $NavigationButton = $paging;
    // paging end

    if($total_rec==0){
        $NavigationButton="<div style='width:100%; height:200px;text-align:center; padding-top:90px' class='hddd'>Binnenkort</div>";
    }

       ?>
            <tr><td colspan="3" style="padding-left:20px" align="center">            <?=$NavigationButton; ?></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
```

thi d letter #fragment-1 are come in title this problem come on IE

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain your problem in a bit more detail? What's wrong where?

Comment: Also I don't see anywhere in your code you instantiate `$db`, did you leave that part out?

Comment: yes. #fragment-1 is comming in title of page which i do not want

Answer (score 2):

This is the old [Flash and IE URL problem](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/issues/detail?id=293). Hope that fixes it for you.

Answer (score -1):

All strange problems are object to investigation.
This investigation called `debugging` in programming science
IBM has a nice article to start from: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

Comment: -1 correct in general, but not helpful to the OP, especially seeing as the problem is most likely a HTML/Flash one (I agree the question is extremely poorly worded, though.)